# 1 distinct row having max value

Tags: sql, oracle

**This is the data I have**

[image]

**I need Unique ID(1 row) with max(Price). So, the output would be:**

[image]

I have tried the following

```
select * from table a
join (select b.id,max(b.price) from table b
group by b.id) c on c.id=a.id;
```

gives the Question as output, because there is no key. I did try the other where condition as well, which gives the original table as output.

Comment: You've tagged this question for multiple database engines. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: If there are multiple rows with a maximum price, which one do you want?

Comment: Any one row with max(price). The other columns don't matter.

Comment: I use both oracle and sql server, wanted to compare performance.

Comment: Is this the maximum price for a particular item? The maximum price of an item purchased by a particular user? ???

Comment: So it's not, like, a homework assignment or anything?

Comment: Wait I ll edit the question, I think the other columns are making it confusing

Comment: If you edit the question, please include your test data and results as text rather than as an image. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this in SQL Server:

**Table**

```
create table ex1 (
    id int, 
    item char(1),
    price int,
    qty int,
    usr char(2)
);
```

**Data**

```
insert into ex1 values
(1, 'a', 7, 1, 'ab'),
(1, 'a', 7, 2, 'ac'),
(2, 'b', 6, 1, 'ab'),
(2, 'b', 6, 1, 'av'),
(2, 'b', 5, 1, 'ab'),
(3, 'c', 5, 2, 'ab'),
(4, 'd', 4, 2, 'ac'),
(4, 'd', 3, 1, 'av');
```

**Query**

```
select a.* from ex1 a
join (
    select id, max(price) as maxprice, min(usr) as minuser
    from ex1
    group by id
) c
    on c.id = a.id
    and a.price = c.maxprice
    and a.usr = c.minuser
order by a.id, a.usr;
```

**Result**

```
id  item price qty  usr
1   a     7    1    ab
2   b     6    1    ab
3   c     5    2    ab
4   d     4    2    ac
```

**Explanation**

In your dataset, ID 1 has 2 records with the same price. You have to make a decision which one you want. So, in the above example, I am showing a single record for the user whose name is lowest alphabetically.

**Alternate method**

SQL Server has ranking function `row_number over()` that can be used as well:

```
select * from (
    select row_number() over( partition by id order by id, price desc, usr) as sr, *
    from ex1
) c where sr = 1;
```

The subquery says - give me all records from the table and give each row a serial number starting with 1 unique to each ID. The rows should be sorted by ID first, then price descending and then usr. The outer query picks out records with sr number 1.

Example here: https://rextester.com/KZCZ25396